# Flutter BLOC and immutability concept for data that changes very often?

Tags: immutability, dart, flutter, bloc

I am new to Dart/Flutter and try to use the Bloc framework for my current project. I am now at the point, where the data, especially in states, is getting more complex.

For example: A certain state holds a big list of items. The items itself holding other items which are holding certain properties etc.

From other programming language i am used to modify those objects/properties by just iterating over the collection and modify the certain property when needed.

If i got it right, the concept of "immutability" means to exactly NOT doing this. Instead, i create/copy every single nested object or property from the origin to a new object.

In the bloc framework - especially states - must be immutable. This is where it feels to me very contra-intuitive. I enforce immutability, even if the data is actually mutated very often (adding list entries, change a property from a to b). This seems to me very odd.

Consider a state where i have 1000 list entries to be shown in a table. Each of them has a property "isSelected" ... for one of those entries i wanna change "isSelected" from "false" to "true", since the user selected it in frontend ... do i have to create/copy every object to a new list now to complete the whole state again? If i got it right, i have to.

I have two issues with this:

1. its very laborious to create such "new" objects with just one or few changes, code complexity will raise and readability will get worse (?) I fear there will be tons of code just for assembling/disassembling objects
2. it will have performance impacts, that is growing with the size of the object (?)

Do i miss something here? How do you solve this in a smart way? I know, there are these copyFrom methods, but they will not prevent performance issues.

Whats the point of making everything immutable?